# Freeform IP Address

Tags: solspace-freeform

Is there a notification variable for the form submitter's IP address in Freeform?

I can't seem to find it in the documentation, but since the IP address is displayed in the Freeform entries view I assume it must exist.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean for the Notifications template in the CP?

The [Freeform docs](https://solspace.com/expressionengine/freeform/docs/entries/#freeform_ip_address) mention the `{freeform:ip_address}` variable. But to get this working in a notification template use `{ip_address}`.

Just tested this and it seems to work (Freeform 4.2.3).